# Regarding locks when creating a new row in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I am trying to get a better grasp on how transactions work in PostgreSQL. I did a lot of research, but I could not find any answers on the following question.

**question 1**

I have two transactions with isolation set to *read committed*, the default. I also have the following table:

```
create table test(a integer primary key);
```

Let's start the first transaction:

```
begin;
insert into test(a) values(1);
```

Now let's start the second transaction and do the same:

```
begin;
insert into test(a) values(1);
```

Now I notice that the second transaction is blocking until the first transaction either commits or rollbacks. Why is that? Why isn't it possible in the second transaction to simply continue after the insert and throw a *unique-key-constraint-exception* when the transaction is requested to be committed **instead of** throwing the exception directly after the insert call?

**question 2**

Now, a second scenario. Let's start from scratch with the first transaction:

```
begin;
insert into test(a) values(1);
delete from test where a = 1;
```

Now let's go to the second transaction:

```
begin;
insert into test(a) values(1);
```

Now I notice that the second transaction is also blocking. Why is it blocking on a row which does not exists anyway?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it blocking on a row which does not exists anyway?

Because both transactions are inserting the same value for the primary key. The second transactions needs to wait for the outcome of the first transaction to know whether it can succeed or not. If the first transactions commits, the second will fail with a primary key violation. If the first transaction rolls back, the insert in the second transaction succeeds.

Comment: That's actually my second question. But the row is actually already deleted in the first transaction. I really don't see why the second transaction need to wait for the outcome of the first in that particular case. Regardless of the outcome of the first transaction (commit or fallback), the second transaction can always commit?

Comment: Because the delete has not been committed - same problem.

Comment: But the insert has also not yet committed? I would really like to understand why that insert is important, but the delete is not.